# NameError: name is not defined function

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I'm trying to write a function in Python that sends a SQL query to the database, stores the retrieved data in a Python Dataframe, and outputs to Excel on a named tab for a number of queries. I got it working when the names for the "shortcut" have been previously run manually but I can't write new "shortcut" names in each instance of the function call.

Can someone please help me debug this issue?

Here's the Python code:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import xlwt as xls_write

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('<Excel File>')

def executeSQL(shortcut, tab, SQL):
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect('<Connection String')
    cursor= conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute (SQL)
    shortcut = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
    shortcut.columns = [rec[0] for rec in cursor.description]
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    shortcut.to_excel(writer, tab, index=False)

executeSQL(tab1, 'Tab 1', "<SQL Statement>")
executeSQL(tab2, 'Tab 2', "<SQL Statement>")
executeSQL(tab3, 'Tab 3', "<SQL Statement>")
executeSQL(tab4, 'Tab 4', "<SQL Statement>")
executeSQL(tab5, 'Tab 5', "<SQL Statement>")
```

Comment: There is no variable named `name`, while the error itself is self-explanatory I don't think the error lies in this code snippet you've posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you passing the shortcut parameter, and then defining it again within the function?  I typically connect using pyodbc, since I don't have your actual data, here is a mock-up of how I would do this:

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import xlwt as xls_write

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('<Excel File>')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('<Connection String')

def executeSQL(tab, SQL, connection):

    df = pd.read_sql(SQL,connection)
    df.to_excel(writer, tab, index=False)

executeSQL('Tab 1', "<SQL Statement>")
executeSQL('Tab 2', "<SQL Statement>")
executeSQL('Tab 3', "<SQL Statement>")
executeSQL('Tab 4', "<SQL Statement>")
executeSQL('Tab 5', "<SQL Statement>")

conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch - I add a <del df> line to clear out the dataframe in the function and it works fine now; thanks for the tip!